# exact calculation of SD on R-squared

Tags: model-selection, standard-deviation, r-squared

In R package "psychometrics" an estimate of SE of R squared of

```
sersq <- sqrt((4*rsq*(1-rsq)^2*(n-k-1)^2)/((n^2-1)*(n+3)))
```

with n sample size, and  k number of parameters if sample size greater than 60 is found. 
Does anyone have a formula for smaller sample size or an exact formula?

I have been through sos - but only found the above? - the real underlying problem is whether comparing models aiming at explaining here a series of concentrations based solely on the R-squared of the individual model predictions vis a vis the measured values is a healthy method